# How would I would I turn this for loop into a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, foreach

Hello All^^  I apologize if this has been asked previously (though I was unable to find a previously posted, similar question myself...).  Also, let me apologize for the simplicity of this question, beforehand.

This is a simple browser game similar to wheel of fortune.  A random quote is generated via js script which the user is supposed to guess via the onscreen keyboard keys.  However, I am unable to compare the user click to that of the quote text content, at current; it is returning "undefined".

I understand (after reading some of the questions on here) that the reason why document.querySelectorAll('.letters') is returning "undefined" is because it is an array, and likely requires a forEach loop, rather than a for loop.

However, is there a way to augment this for loop to compare the button click event target value to that of the document.querySelectorAll('.letters') array value?  If not, how would I write this as a for each loop?  I have tried to re-write it as such for the last hour or so with no luck : /

Is it not possible to include this in a function with an event listener?

I do appreciate your time.

problem code:

```
qwerty.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if ( event.target.tagName === "BUTTON" ) {
       event.target.className = "chosen";
      for( let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++ ) {
          if( event.target.innerText === letters.textContent.toLowerCase() ) {
              letters.className = 'show';
              matched += 1;
          }
       }
    }
 });
```

full code:

```
//Keyboard and game element variables

const qwerty = document.getElementById('qwerty');
const phrase = document.getElementById('phrase');
const keyLetters = document.querySelectorAll('.keyrow button').innerText;

//hidden letters of phrase
const letters = document.querySelectorAll('.letters');

//Game score 

const missed = 0;
const matched = 0;

//Start button (hides start screen overlay and begins game)
const startGame = document.querySelector('.btn_reset');

startGame.addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.start').style.display = 'none'; 
});


//Game quotes

const quotes = [
["René Descartes"        , "I think therefore I am"],
["Friedrich Nietzsche"   , "What does not kill me makes me stronger"],
["Socrates"              , "The unexamined life is not worth living"],
["Sir Winston Churchill" , "If you are going through hell keep going"],
["Winnie the Pooh"       , "Doing nothing often leads to the very best of something"],
["Aldous Huxley"         , "Never have so many been manipulated so much by so few"],
["Albert Einstein"       , "The most beautiful experience we can have is the mysterious"]
];


//Generate random quote

const getRandomPhraseAsArray = () => {
    //create random number between 1 - 7 for quote selection
    let randNum = Math.floor( Math.random() * (quotes.length) );
    //retrieve object value (quote) with random number
    let randQuote = quotes[randNum][1];
    //select the ul .phrase div
    const ul = document.querySelector('#phrase ul');
    //Append to li element created in const li 
    randQuote = randQuote.toString().split("");
    //iterate though each string value in randQuote, create an li element
    //then set the innerText of the li to the string value

    for( let i = 0; i < randQuote.length; i++ ) {
        const li = document.createElement("li");
        ul.appendChild(li);
        li.innerText = randQuote[i]; 
            if ( randQuote[i] != " " ) {
                li.className = "letter";
            } else {
                li.className = "space";
            }
        };
}; 

getRandomPhraseAsArray();

//keypress function

qwerty.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if ( event.target.tagName === "BUTTON" ) {
         event.target.className = "chosen";
        for( let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++ ) {
             if( event.target.innerText === letters.textContent.toLowerCase() ) {
                 letters.className = 'show';
                 matched += 1;
             }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: No, a collection of elements should use `for of` or a regular loop, although depending on the Browser may work with a `for in` loop. `.letters` must be undefined, since it would return an Array Like Object otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.  StackSlave was correct.  A for/of loop was what was required to iterate through the array.

```
qwerty.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
if ( event.target.tagName === "BUTTON" ) {
     event.target.className = "chosen";
    for( const letter of letters ) {
         if( event.target.innerText === letter.textContent.toLowerCase() ) {
             letter.className = 'show';
             matched += 1;
         }
    }
}
```

});